# avoid double - not in - select on search

Tags: mysql

I have a search engine. I don't want blocked users to be on this search.
I have table block:

```
id - autoincrement
user - who is blocking
block - who is blocked
```

and table users.
I have this select and it is working fine:

```
select c.nome, c.user, c.id, p.foto from users c 
left join profile_picture p on c.id=p.user
where (c.id not in (select `block` from block where user = '1')) //avoid double block select
and (c.id not in (select `user` from block where block = '1')) //avoid double block select
and (c.user like '%uk%' OR c.nome like '%uk%')
```

The problem is, can I avoid this double not in, first to avoid the blocked user to be on the search and the secound to avoid the blocked user to search who blocked him. Can I avoid this double block table select for both sides?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine both queries as one with a `UNION`

```
select c.nome, c.user, c.id, p.foto 
from users c 
left join profile_picture p on c.id=p.user
where c.id not in 
(
  select `block` as  from block where user = '1'
  union  
  select `user` as block from block where block = '1'
) 
and (c.user like '%uk%' OR c.nome like '%uk%')
```

Comment: how this answer "Can I avoid this double block table select for both sides?"

Comment: @JorgeCampos I understand that the OP doesn't want to use 2 "NOT IN's". Is that not the case?

Comment: I guess I didn't paid enough attention to the question. Fair enough! Sorry :)

Comment: in fact I'd like to avoid double select, to scan the table block twice. but my question is a little ambiguous indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this just with `JOINs` and only one `SELECT` from block

```
select c.nome, c.user, c.id, p.foto 
from users c 
left join profile_picture p on c.id=p.user
left join (select * from block where user='1' or block='1') b1 on b1.user=c.id or b1.block=c.id
where b1.user is not null and b1.block is not null
and (c.user like '%uk%' OR c.nome like '%uk%')
```